# Apache Shiro MD5Hash and SimpleHash generate different values

Tags: java, security, shiro

I am new to security and Apache Shiro. I am learning Shiro recently.
As far as I have learnt there are two ways to hash a value by using md5, the code is below.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SecureRandomNumberGenerator generator = new SecureRandomNumberGenerator();
    ByteSource nextByteSource = generator.nextBytes();
    Md5Hash md5Hash = new Md5Hash("234", ByteSource.Util.bytes(nextByteSource));

    int iterations = 2;
    md5Hash.setIterations(iterations);
    System.out.println("md5hash to hex: "+md5Hash.toHex());
    SimpleHash hash = new SimpleHash("md5","234",ByteSource.Util.bytes(nextByteSource),iterations);
    System.out.println("simple hash to hex: "+hash.toHex());
}
```

Both Md5Hash and SimpleHash use the same algorithm, same salt, same input and same iterations, but the outputs are different:

```
md5hash to hex: 93a2bb8a10727716085e3ae234a90fc8
simple hash to hex: e691e292d8300f29c6e0c448f1ecba76
```

What makes the two hashed values different?

Comment: Does changing `iterations` do anything?

Comment: Yes. They both return the same hashed value if the iterations are removed (default is 1). Based on the SimpleHash's api: hashIterations - the number of times the source argument hashed for attack resiliency. If the iteration is set to 2, I think the hash algorithm is ran twice, the second round's input (source) is the first round's output and they use the same salt, it is supposed to generate the same hashed value for the second round. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The md5Hash you are creating is with just on iteration while via SimpleHash its 2 iteration so the change should be:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
int iterations = 2;     

SecureRandomNumberGenerator generator = new SecureRandomNumberGenerator();
        ByteSource nextByteSource = generator.nextBytes();
        Md5Hash md5Hash = new Md5Hash("234", ByteSource.Util.bytes(nextByteSource),iterations);


        md5Hash.setIterations(iterations);
        System.out.println("md5hash to hex: "+md5Hash.toHex());
        SimpleHash hash = new SimpleHash("md5","234",ByteSource.Util.bytes(nextByteSource),iterations);
        System.out.println("simple hash to hex: "+hash.toHex());
    }
```